# Amazon SP-API get products with variations and all informations about product

Tags: laravel, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to use Amazon SP API SDK to get my all products from inventory, but I don't know how to do that, I tried with catalog items, but it show to me products that are not my products, and if I use `getListingsItem` I need to use sku and to take exact product, and I need whole my products with their variants and images.

```
$response=$this->sdk->listingsItems()->getListingsItem(
      $this->accessToken,
      $region,
      'A2BSV6DB9TAL2',
      'sku123',
      ['A1PA6795UKMFR9'],
      null,
      null,
    );
```